# Can't bind callable object closure

Tags: php, oop, closures, php-7

Working on a router library, I'm trying to enable different approaches to passing callbacks to route handlers. One of these approaches is classes with the magic [`__invoke`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) method. Instances of such classes identify as callable (`is_callable($obj) === true`), so I'd imagine you could pass them to [`Closure::fromCallable`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php) and bind them to a scope object.
However, as the following example demonstrates, calling `bindTo` on the closure doesn't work, and I don't understand what is going wrong here.

```
class Invokable {
    public function __invoke() {
        return $this->foo + 20;
    }
}

class Context {
    public $foo = 22; 
}

$context = new Context(); // Create arbitrary object to bind the closure to
$test = new Invokable(); // Create instance of the single-shot class

$closure = Closure::fromCallable($test); // This is fine and returns a callable 
$boundClosure = $closure->bindTo($context); // <-- Crashes

echo $boundClosure(); // Expected ouput: 42
```

Executing this code in PHP 7.3.0 results in the following output:

```
Warning:     Cannot bind method Invokable::__invoke() to object of class Context
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string
```

Comment: Note the answer from that question which says: "If you want to bind an closure to an new object, it must not be an fake closure, or the new object must be compatible with the old one ([source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_closures.c#L78))."

Comment: Also note: https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/600680897550098432 and https://twitter.com/Ocramius/status/600705252539691008 =D

Comment: For example: if `Context extends Invokable` then your code will work

Comment: @RobbieAverill huh, that explains why this isn't working. My use case is to bind `Controller` instance methods to a `Container` context, allowing for route handlers that have access to the DI container using `$this->get('service')`. Will have to find another way as it seems.